# Change color fo row when using DT

Tags: r, dt

I´m trying to print a table in html markdown using knitr and DT as follows.

```
library(knitr)
library(DT)

my_vals = tab$Final.amplicons.nb
my_colors = ifelse(my_vals < 5000,'orange','white')


 DT::datatable(tab) %>% 
   formatStyle(
  'Final.amplicons.nb',
  target = 'row',
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(my_vals,my_colors)
  )
```

No cell is colored orange although i have a value of 55 that should be colored. What´s wrong ??

```
> my_vals
  [1] 112123 112778 116665  19466  85371  68394  72076  81255  59810  51696  73548  86320  57003  80294  87131  73266  68088  67708 100771  90976
 [21] 101821  79905  60232  49591  56402  55209  55079  85390     55  85336  55456  77793  60298  99197  64990  47017 104828  89953 100005  87908
 [41]  65121  69082  64514  68753  85883  53052  95897  78756  76555  77574  72316  68203  67707  52106  59910  99580  82437  74173  55874  66525
 [61]  58873  92038 102226 108297  80314  86783  63404  60277  60364  90651  81586  76373  73294  85939  43570  81557  56468  52573  62760  72203
 [81]  69894  89835  49966  73430  63710  51216  49801  79938  92529  67400  89471  77138  77554  61461  77973  62236  58973  63779  72383  83147
[101]  81281  92054   5100   9572   7529
> my_colors
  [1] "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white" 
 [16] "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "orange" "white" 
 [31] "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white" 
 [46] "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white" 
 [61] "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white" 
 [76] "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white" 
 [91] "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white"  "white" 

> packageVersion("DT")
[1] ‘0.10.1’
```

Not that same code will work with `target='cell'.` Seems specific to `target='row'`

Comment: This looks like a bug. `0.10.1` is the development version, right? Have you tried with the CRAN version?

Comment: this was fixed  here https://github.com/juba/rmdformats/commit/6afc5a13d2d2d00128d2728b4d07755c73539594